# Vue-Typed-JS (Nuxt, Vuetify). Unable to center content

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I am currently using Nuxt and Vuetify to build a PWA and I am using vue-typed-js for a typing animation.

https://github.com/Orlandster/vue-typed-js#default-import

However, I am struggling to get the content of the typing to be justified in the center.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="text-center justify-center d-flex flex-column min-vh-100">
      <h1>Hello!</h1>
      <vue-typed-js 
      :strings="['Im Barra, <b><span>UX Designer</span></b> and <b><span>Researcher</span></b> &#128075;']" 
      :showCursor="false" 
      :typeSpeed="75">
        <p class="typing"></p>
      </vue-typed-js>
      <transition name="scroll" appear>
        <div class="scrolldown-wrapper" v-if="show">
          <div class="scrolldown">
            <svg height="30" width="10">
              <circle class="scrolldown-p1" cx="5" cy="15" r="2" />
              <circle class="scrolldown-p2" cx="5" cy="15" r="2" />
            </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
      </transition>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

My H1 tag is justified correctly, but the vue-typed-js content is still justified to the left of the page.

I have attached a screenshot that shows how its displaying. If I disable the "display: flex" prop from the browser css, I get the desired result. However I am not sure how to actually override this in my nuxt app.

[image]

Any ideas on how I can center that content?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use v-row with justify="center" and align="center":

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="text-center justify-center d-flex flex-column min-vh-100">
      <h1>Hello!</h1>
      <v-row align="center" justify="center">
        <vue-typed-js 
        :strings="['Im Barra, <b><span>UX Designer</span></b> and <b><span>Researcher</span></b> &#128075;']" 
        :showCursor="false" 
        :typeSpeed="75">
          <p class="typing"></p>
        </vue-typed-js>
      </v-row>
      <transition name="scroll" appear>
        <div class="scrolldown-wrapper" v-if="show">
          <div class="scrolldown">
            <svg height="30" width="10">
              <circle class="scrolldown-p1" cx="5" cy="15" r="2" />
              <circle class="scrolldown-p2" cx="5" cy="15" r="2" />
            </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
      </transition>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: So simple (facepalm)...Thanks David! Lockdown is causing me to miss the basics it seems. Appreciate the response. B